# Legittimità di 'lunghe lunghe'

Tags: meaning, adjectives

Mentre stavo facendo un esercizio della *Grammatica pratica* di Susanna Nocchi, ho trovato il seguente paragrafo (pag. 11):

> La *città* è sul *mare* Adriatico. Ha pochi *abitanti* d'inverno ma d'estate ci sono sempre molti *turisti*: specialmente *tedeschi*, *slavi* e *scandinavi*. Ci sono molte *spiagge* private e pubbliche, **lunghe lunghe** e con *bambini* che giocano con la sabbia, *ragazzi* che giocano con il pallone e *persone* al sole. La sera aprono i *ristoranti*, le *discoteche* e i *bar* e la *notte* è lunghissima e divertentissima!!. Come si chiama la città? [corsivo mio]

Sapevo il significato di *lunghe*, però perché 'lunghe lunghe'? È una tecnica per intensificare l'aggettivo, un superlativo? È valido il suo uso o è considerato substandard? Ha sbagliato l'autrice o l'editore?

Comment: PS: La città è Alba Adriatica, potrebbe essere?

Comment: Secondo l'esercizio seguente, la città è Rimini. Va bene, io ci sono stata d'inverno e non mi è sembrato che ci fossero pochissimi abitanti, però.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ripetere l'aggettivo di grado positivo è uno dei modi per ottenere il superlativo assoluto.

Nel tuo caso, "lunghe lunghe" significa "molto lunghe".

Questa modalità è perfettamente corretta nell'italiano standard:
[https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/reduplicazione-espressiva_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/reduplicazione-espressiva_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/)

Come linuxfan suggerisce, questi tipi di ripetizione sono più adatti in ambiti non formali poiché, come riportato nel link, "la reduplicazione servirebbe ad esprimere una certa emozione del parlante".

A mio parere, dà un po' l'idea di linguaggio infantile ma non è sempre così. Come dice DaG, è stata utilizzata da fior fior di scrittori (ecco un esempio di reduplicazione senza tono infantile).

P.S. = la definizione si addice a molte località della Riviera Romagnola.

Comment: Aggiungerei che questi tipi di ripetizione sono più adatti in ambiti non formali poiché, come cita il tuo link, "la reduplicazione servirebbe ad esprimere una certa emozione del parlante". In più la ripetizione ha un che d'impreciso...

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Fatto, grazie.

Comment: Grazie per la risposta e per il link alla Treccani. Non direi però che di per sé dia “un senso di linguaggio infantile”: uno degli ambiti in cui compare è questo, ma è anche usato da molti scrittori (come dice quell'articolo) per vari possibili effetti di intensificazione. Fra gli esempi non infantili a cui lì si fa solo riferimento, rimandando alla grammatica di Serianni, ci sono “nel letto divenuto duro duro, sotto le coperte divenute pesanti pesanti” (Manzoni) e “La sua figura alta alta e trista era diventata odiosa a tutta quanta la famiglia” (Morante).

Comment: @DaG Quella è la mia impressione, aggiungo commento.